# Can not bind a variable inside setInterval() in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

i have used setInterval() method to show current datetime in my angular 6 project.But datatime variable value not changing after setInterval() call.its taking onload value.Here is my code

### .ts

```
constructor(private data: DataService) {
    this.data.get_data('current-gmt-date',true)//service call
               .subscribe((data:any) => {
                  this.now = data.data.currentDateTime;//2019-01-21 20:30:0
    });
    setInterval(() => {
        this.now.setSeconds( this.now.getSeconds() + 1 );
        console.log(this.now);
        }, 1000); 
}
```

### And .html

```
<span class="dateClock">Time:  {{now | date:'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss ' : 'UTC' }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `interval` from `rxjs`

```
// RxJS v6+
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

//emit value in sequence every 1 second
const source = interval(1000);.
const subscribe = source.subscribe(() => console.log(new Date()));
```

in your case

```
const subscribe = source.subscribe(() => this.now = new Date()));
```

edit: use `mergeMap` for calling your observable in interval of 1 second

```
source.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => this.data.get_data('current-gmt-date',true))
)
.subscribe((data) => this.now = data.data.currentDateTime)
```

Comment: this.now is getting from service call not Date() in my case

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember your request is **asynchronous**, so it takes a while for the response to arrive, in meanwhile, it will use the initial value you have for `now`. What you need to do is to add your interval inside the subscribe block:

```ts
constructor(private data: DataService) {
  this.data.get_data('current-gmt-date',true) //service call
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
       this.now = data.data.currentDateTime; //2019-01-21 20:30:0

       setInterval(() => {
         this.now.setSeconds( this.now.getSeconds() + 1 );
         console.log(this.now);
       }, 1000); 
    });
}
```

Remember to use `clearInterval` in `OnDestroy`.

Read more about ansynchronous behavior: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)